# How to persist the dynamic original time formatting and overwrite end and start of the axis label ticks in Apache ECharts?

Tags: echarts

I want to create `axisLabel` formatter, such that instead of the `Timestamp` it returns the original time ticks(maybe even the context), but for the min/max labels it shows the full date?

Or maybe it's more feasible on the slider, there I want to always show (not just on emphasis) the full start/end dates below the respective handles?

###### Current slider settings

```
        {
          type: 'slider',
          orient: 'horizontal',
          show: true,
          showDataShadow: false,
          moveHandleSize: 8,
          handleSize: '150%',
          filterMode: 'weakFilter',
          textStyle: {
            color: 'red',
          },
        },
```

Current example (slider hovered):

[image]

I've tried reading the documentation and the source code, but didn't manage to find anything that wouldn't involve complex logic.